# Error while setting char column in SQL table as Primary key in hibernate mapping

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a hibernate mapping class and SQL table where SQL design of that table is:

[image: as]

Hibernate mapping class is defined as, setting char for data type does not work also:

```
<class name="com.model.TmCurrencies" table="tm_currencies">

        <id name="currencyCode" column="currency_code" type="char">
            <generator class="uuid" />
        </id> 
        <property name="currencyCode" column="currency_code" type="string"/>
        <property name="alphaCode" column="alpha_code" type="string"/>
        <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
        <property name="nrDecimals" column="nr_decimals" type="int"/>
        <property name="rate" column="rate" type="double"/>

        <!-- <property name="participantId" column="participant_id" type="long"/> -->
    </class>    
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Java Model class:

```
public class TmCurrencies {

private char currencyCode;
private String alphaCode;
private String name;
private int nrDecimals;
private double rate;
}
```

In the SQL table, currency_code is the primary key which is char array. If I set it to string in hibernate mapping and in java model class I get error saying data would be truncated. Also this char key does not auto increment so I have to set the value from the code itself.

Please suggest me how to tackle and set data type for this char primary key with no auto increment in hibernate mapping class and java code?

Comment: Depending on how it's formatted a UUID will be 36 characters (without braces) or 38 characters (with braces). It won't fit in a char(3) column.

Comment: its not an auto incrementing key. I have to set a manual key in this table but I don't know how to set this to manual in hibernate :    <generator class="uuid" />
Is there any alternative class for this?